# Remove blue box when clicked?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, webkit

I am using Material UI and have never seen this behavior before. It it happening on many of my buttons and would like to change this and just use the ripple effect. I am not sure what is causing this behavior. This blue box stays there until I click away. I would like to not see it at all , thanks!!

Update: This style is being added during :focus but it is not adding an Mui class.

[image: Before:]

[image: After]

```
<IconButton>
    <ChevronRightIcon />
</IconButton>
```

Comment: which MUI component are you using?

Comment: @alisasani just made the edit. I am also seeing it on my ToggleButtons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called an [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline). You can remove it by setting the corresponding css property to `none` as such:

```
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this after a little more investigation into the chrome dev tools.

```
button:focus {
    outline: 1px dotted;
    outline 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color
}
```

was being added to the button. Not sure from where but adding

```
button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

to `App.css` did the job. If anyone can comment below why this was added/why I have never encountered this before, that'd be much appreciated!